# Why my code can't locate the data table?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, datatable, report

I have this code below to generate a report. My problem is why one of the content of my data table can't locate by my code? The `ds.dt_ProposedSeminars` is the table.

```
public JsonResult ReportProposal(int year)
{
    string Userkey = "gHeOai6bFzWskyUxX2ivq4+pJ7ALwbzwF55dZvy/23BrHAfvDVj7mg  ";
    string PassKey = "lLAHwegN8zdS7mIZyZZj+EmzlkUXkvEYxLvgAYjuBVtU8sw6wKXy2g  ";

    JsonResult result = new JsonResult();
    MemoryStream oStream;

    PCSO_ProposedSeminars rpt = new PCSO_ProposedSeminars();
    dsPCSO_TrainingProgram ds = new dsPCSO_TrainingProgram();

    //-----------------------------------------------------
    var seminars = db.Certificates
            .Where(x => x.Year.Value.Year == year && !x.IsApproved.HasValue)
            .Select(z => z).Distinct();

    foreach (var train in seminars)
    {
             string trainingProgram = train.CertificateName;
             string resourcePerson = train.ResourceSpeaker;
             string target = "";

             var classifications = db.CertificateTrainingClassifications.Where(a => a.CertificateId == train.CertificateId).Select(b=>b.TrainingClassification.Classification);

             int x = 1;

             foreach (var classification in classifications)
             {
                 if (classifications.Count() > 1)
                 {
                     if (x == 1) target += classification;
                     else target +=  ", " + classification;
                 }
                 else target += classification;

                 x++;
             }

             if (train.TargetParticipants.HasValue)
             {
                 target += "/" + train.TargetParticipants.Value + ((train.TargetParticipants != null) ? " pax" : "");
             }

             if (train.IsPerBatch.Value)
             {
                 target += "/batch";
             }

             string duration = train.Duration.Value + " days";
             decimal estimatedExpenses = new decimal();
             estimatedExpenses = train.EstimatedExpenses.Value;

             ds.dt_ProposedSeminars.Adddt_ProposedSeminarsRow(
                     trainingProgram,
                     resourcePerson,
                     target,
                     duration,
                     estimatedExpenses);
        }

        DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
        dtable = ds.dt_ProposedSeminars;

        rpt.SetDataSource(dtable);
        rpt.Refresh();
        rpt.SetParameterValue(0, year);
        rpt.SetParameterValue(1, "");
        rpt.SetParameterValue(2, "Head, Training Unit, Admin Department");

        oStream = (MemoryStream)rpt.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);

        string filename = Convert.ToString((DateTime.Now.Month) + Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.Day) + Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.Year) + Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.Hour) + Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.Minute) + Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.Second) + Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.Millisecond)) + "RequestApplication";
        var len = oStream.Length;

        FileTransferServiceClient client2 = new FileTransferServiceClient();
        RemoteFileInfo rmi = new RemoteFileInfo();
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;

        DownloadRequest dr = new DownloadRequest();
        string fId = client2.UploadFileGetId("", filename, len, PassKey, Userkey, oStream);
        result.Data = new
         {
             fileId = fId,
             filename = filename
         };
        rpt.Close();
        rpt.Dispose();

        oStream.Close();
        oStream.Dispose();

        result.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
        return result;
    }
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Here is the error.

> 'PIMS_Reports.TrainingProgram.dsPCSO_TrainingProgram' does not contain a definition for 'dt_ProposedSeminars' and no extension method 'dt_ProposedSeminars' accepting a first arguement of type
>
> 'PIMS_Reports.TrainingProgram.dsPCSO_TrainingProgram' could not be found (are you missing a using directive assembly reference?)

[image]

Comment: @GrantWinney Ok I will. I will edit it.. sorry for late reply I take noon break.

Comment: Thank you all I found the problem. And now i got new problem to solve :D

Answer (score -1):

The error message states that your dsPCSO_TrainingProgram class does not contain a method or property named dt_PropsedSeminars.

What does that class look like?

Comment: @J Omundson look at the picture.

Comment: I did look at the error message.  From your example, you are creating a new dsPCSO_TrainingProgram class.  `dsPCSO_TrainingProgram ds = new dsPCSO_TrainingProgram();` That class cannot find a property or method named dt_ProposedSeminars.  So either you do not have the class referenced it at the top of your current Controller or there is something wrong with the class itself, which is why I asked to see the dsPCSO_TrainingProgram class.

Comment: The dt_ProposedSeminars must be seen after I updated my dll report. I don't know what is happening to my project.